# JIRA request token fetch error using Python

Tags: python, oauth, jira

I am trying to configure and use OAuth to authenticate and request token using Python. I have generated jira private key.

```
import requests
from oauthlib.oauth1 import SIGNATURE_RSA,SIGNATURE_HMAC
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
from jira.client import JIRA
import time


def read(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return f.read()


CONSUMER_KEY = "OauthKey"
RSA_KEY = read("jira_privatekey.pem")

JIRA_SERVER = "http://rhtstngjira012:8080"

REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = JIRA_SERVER + "/plugins/servlet/oauth/request-token"
AUTHORIZE_URL = JIRA_SERVER + "/plugins/servlet/oauth/authorize"
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = JIRA_SERVER + "/plugins/servlet/oauth/access-token"

oauth = OAuth1Session(CONSUMER_KEY, signature_type="auth_header", signature_method=SIGNATURE_RSA, rsa_key=RSA_KEY)
request_token = oauth.fetch_request_token(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL)
```

But while requesting tokens, I am getting the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Access_Tokens_JIRA.py", line 23, in <module>
    request_token = oauth.fetch_request_token(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL)
  File "/PYTHON_SCRIPTS/Environments/TESTING/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py", line 287, in fetch_request_token
    token = self._fetch_token(url, **request_kwargs)
  File "/PYTHON_SCRIPTS/Environments/TESTING/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py", line 369, in _fetch_token
    raise TokenRequestDenied(error % (r.status_code, r.text), r)
requests_oauthlib.oauth1_session.TokenRequestDenied: Token request failed with code 401, response was 'oauth_problem=signature_invalid&oauth_signature=ABC&oauth_signature_base_string=POST%26http%253A%252F%252Frhtstngjira012%253A8080%252Fplugins%252Fservlet%252Foauth%252Frequest-token%26oauth_consumer_key%253DOauthKey%2526oauth_nonce%123%2526oauth_signature_method%253DRSA-SHA1%2526oauth_timestamp%253D1630512420%2526oauth_version%253D1.0&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1'
```

I have installed all latest libraries and have generated keys too. Could you please advise what I can change to request tokens from JIRA?

Answer (score 0):

You should create API token and encode to base64 the whole String email:your-api-token.

You have to create API token for your user as described here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Rakesh. I am following steps mentioned here - https://github.com/lakshmi-kannan/jira-oauth-access-token-generator/blob/master/generate_access_token.py